# Running an rsync server on an Android device over a non-WiFi, cell-based connection?

Tags: mobile-data, services, rsync

I asked a somewhat similar question to this recently (see [Rsync-like downloads over adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224753/rsync-like-downloads-over-adb)), but what I'm asking here is a little bit different.

Also, if this question belongs in a different forum, I apologize in advance, and am happy to repost it elsewhere.

I want to set up an actual `rsync` server on my Android device, but one which works without a WiFi connection. In other words, I want it to work over a normal "cell phone" data connection. The only ways I've been able to get an `rsync` server to work so far is over a WiFi connection.

I know how to determine the device's assigned IP address in real time (even with a cell-based, non-WiFi data connection) and how make that IP address available to sources outside of the device. But I haven't been able to get the device to listen on that specific IP address when I do not have a WiFi connection.

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to Android through SSH over 3G/4G public IP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203996/how-to-connect-to-android-through-ssh-over-3g-4g-public-ip). If it is an ssh or an rsync server does not matter, as you usually don't get a public IP in the cell phone network you can't access your device from outside.

Comment: Actually, the topic you suggested does address my question, so I will move over to there. Even without a public IP, there *might* be a way to accomplish this via port forwarding to a proxy -- or something similar. I'll ask under that topic. Thank you.